# Connection reset from WCF service when sending file from Android

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I am battling a connection reset issue and I am hoping someone can help me diagnose it. We have a WCF Service that has a function that receives a file (a SQLite database) and saves it to the server. Periodically, a client will get a connection reset exception when uploading the file.

We have never been able to reproduce this issue in development. It has only ever occurred in production, and even then, inconsistently. This will happen on a client one day, but not the next. We have manually taken the same file off of the client and moved it to one in development to debug sending to the same production server only to have it then succeed without issue. It will happen on some production servers, but not others - again, inconsistently.

The files are relatively small, usually between 500kb and 10mb.

Here is the service function:

```cpp
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           UriTemplate = "SendData",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public GenericObject SendData(Stream data)
{
    GenericObject go = new GenericObject();
    
    try
    {
        string fileName = "SomePathToFile.db";

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);

        int offset = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
        
        while ((offset = databaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, offset);
        
        fs.Close();
        
        go.Item = "Send successful";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        go.Error = "Error sending data\n\n" + ex.Message;
        
        //Do some error logging
        ...
    }
    
    return go;
}
```

It simply takes the file stream and saves it locally to the server. It returns a generic JSON object that has a success message or an error message, if something goes wrong. Note: the client does not get the object back and no exception is ever logged on the server.

Here is the function on the Android side that is sending the file (we have added some retry logic in an attempt to help reduce the error):

```java
public void sendData(String serviceURL, int attemptNumber)
{

    //Declare all streams/disposable objects so that we can reset them if an error occurs
    FileInputStream fs = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    boolean connectionResetError = false;

    File tempFile = null;

    try
    {
        //Do some stuff to write the db file to the cache directory for temporary storage
        tempFile = new File(getCacheDir(), "SomeFile.db");

        ...
        

        //Open the cache copy of the file for reading
        fs = new FileInputStream(tempFile);

        //Establish URL to the service
        URL url = new URL(serviceURL);

        // Open an HTTP  connection to the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);      // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);     // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false);   // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        
        //Tried both of these options based on other Stack Overflow suggestions
        //conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); 

        //Open a stream on the connection to write the file
        os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;

        //Determine file size and if a buffer is needed
        bytesAvailable = fs.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read from the file into the buffer
        bytesRead = fs.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        //Continue reading while there is still more to be read from the file
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            //write the buffer to the connection
            os.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            //See if there is more to be read from the file and then read
            bytesAvailable = fs.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fs.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        //Get the response and message from the connection
        int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        //Flush the output stream
        os.flush();

        if (serverResponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            //If response is "OK", read the data that was sent

            //Open a reader for the response and buffer it
            isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            //String to hold the response
            String responseString;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Read the response
            while ((responseString = in.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(responseString);

            //Return the response that was read
            jResponse = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            //If any other response is received, return the message
            response.putString("Error", serverResponseMessage);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //An error occurred

        //Check to see if it's the connection reset error and if we've tried less than 3 times
        if(ex instanceof java.net.SocketException && ex.getMessage().equals("Connection reset") && attemptNumber < 3)
        {
            //If so, make a note so we can try again
            connectionResetError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //If not, just pass along the error
            response.putString("Error", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //Dispose of everything before we quit or try again

        try { if (fs != null) fs.close(); } catch(IOException e){}
        try { if (in != null) in.close(); } catch(IOException e){}
        try { if (isr != null) isr.close(); } catch(IOException e){}
        try { if (os != null) os.close(); } catch(IOException e){}
        try { if (conn != null) conn.disconnect(); } catch(Exception e){}
        
        if(tempFile != null && tempFile.exists())
            tempFile.delete();
    }

    //If we're going to try again, do so and increment the attempt number
    if(connectionResetError)
    {
        sendData(serviceURL, attemptNumber+1);
    }
}
```

We have set up Wireshark on one of the servers in an attempt to debug, but I am not familiar enough with it for it to meaningful. What I do know is that I see the request, some of the data being transferred, and then the reset.
[image: Beginning of transfer]

[image: End of transfer]

Any suggestions that you may have or guidance on debugging would be very helpful.

Comment: just unraleted comments: `bytesAvailable = fs.available();` what for? you should write `bytesRead` bytes and read  `bufferSize` aways ... next what is the purpose of `DataOutputStream`? you can write directly to `OutputStream`

Comment: @Selvin. Thanks. The answer to these is just that that's what we found in samples online. Our original version of this function was written in 2013 and had been working with no issue until early this year. When we started experiencing issues, one thing we tried was looking to more recent samples, since the framework has changed a bit in those 7 years. Our original function had neither of the issues you point out:

`OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();`
`byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];`
`int offset = 0;`
`while ((offset = fs.read(buffer)) != -1) {`
`os.write(buffer);`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

An abnormal connection reset usually only means that the connection has been closed. This may be caused by network issues. I suggest you set a timeout in the configuration file to avoid this problem:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding openTimeout="00:10:00"
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

You can enable WCF tracing on client side to gather the info from the error clients.
For details about WCF tracing, please refer to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand that the connection is being closed unexpectedly. If this were an isolated incident, I would agree that it was simply a network issue. However, some clients are experiencing this daily, others weekly, and other still not at all. It seems odd for this to suddenly start happening at various locations after years of not. The error occurs after 10-30 seconds of sending the data, so I do not think a timeout, especially a 10 minute one, would resolve the issue here. Thank you for the information on tracing. I will enable that and go over the logs.